# Basic Assert in xUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

Looking for a basic assert in **xUnit**. This is simple in **MSTest** and **NUnit**.

```
Assert.Fail("some message"); // MSTest - works
Assert.Fail("some message"); // NUnit - works (same syntax)
Assert.Fail("some message"); // xUnit - does not compile
```

The project is a C# `xUnit Test Project (.NET Core)` in Visual Studio 2019.

#### UPDATE

Responding to comments about what version of xUnit is installed. The NuGet package was installed automatically by Visual Studio when the project was created. The `.csproj` file reveals that Visual Studio installed version "2.4.0".

Comment: We know xUnit is open source, so we can go look at the code. I did a web search for xUnit, found their homepage, [found their list of GitHub projects](https://xunit.net/#projects), including one that deals with assertions. Did you find that as well? Did you find what you were looking for?

Comment: There is a `Fail` method available in Xunit.Assertions, the thing is that it hasn't been released since 2018. If you use the latest prerelease version (2.4.2-pre.12) you get a Fail method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XUnit assert message is a parameter. It is part of all **Assert Extension Methods**.

For example :

```
Assert.False(true, "true will never be false")
```

Comment: The [source code suggests](https://github.com/xunit/assert.xunit/blob/43e3e208a597bc1a4c77f2665f39f98e7401c157/FailAsserts.cs#L24) that the code you've written isn't necessary.

Comment: Not available for externals xUnit : https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/2027

Answer (score 1):

[xunit 2.4.2-pre.12](https://www.nuget.org/packages/xunit/2.4.2-pre.12) contains the [`Assert.Fail(string)` method](https://github.com/xunit/assert.xunit/blob/main/FailAsserts.cs#L24).

However, as was pointed out in the comments, this was recently added so prior versions do not contain the `Assert.Fail()` method.

Comment: xUnit was installed as a NuGet package, but automatically by Visual Studio 2019. Am trying to track down what version is installed. The syntax `Assert.Fail(string)` definitely does NOT work in whatever was installed automatically by VS2019.

Comment: Check your `.csproj` file for the version in the `<PackageReference>` element.

Comment: Thanks, good tip. Can confirm the version of xUnit is "2.4.0". Will add that detail to the question.